# Definition of whitespace in JSON

Tags: json, parsing, unicode, utf-8, whitespace

JSON specifies that "Whitespace can be inserted between any pair of tokens." What it does not specify is exactly what whitespace is. Should I read this as "old-fashioned ASCII whitespace" or "the entire spectrum of Unicode whitespace"?

In other words, when parsing JSON, are U+2000, U+2001, U+FEFF etc. valid whitespace characters between tokens?

Comment: Where did you take your citation ? When you read the spec, whitespace are pretty well defined.

Comment: It's from the "JSON railroad diagram page" http://www.json.org/

Comment: Yes, but this page is an introduction which links to a specification...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Insignificant whitespace is defined in the [RFC4627 for JSON](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt):

> Insignificant whitespace is allowed before or after any of the six
>   structural characters.

```
  ws = *(
            %x20 /              ; Space
            %x09 /              ; Horizontal tab
            %x0A /              ; Line feed or New line
            %x0D                ; Carriage return
        )
```

By the way, the default encoding is UTF-8:

> JSON text SHALL be encoded in Unicode.  The default encoding is UTF-8.

That being said, I don't think they intended to accept all forms of [Unicode spaces](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/spaces.html) in the original implementation.

Comment: Awesome. This RFC document is much more detailed than the json.org page I was using.